# How does nginx construct file paths in a location block?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to rewrite `GET /` to `/srv/app/static/index.html`. I'm close with these few directives:

```
root /srv/app/static;
location /static {
    alias /srv/app/static;
}
location = / {
    alias /srv/app/static/index.html;
}
```

So, when I `GET /static`, nginx serves the file at `/srv/app/static/index.html` and I'm happy.

But, when I `GET /`, nginx returns a 404. Checking the log, I see it's trying to access the file `/srv/app/static/index.htmlindex.html` (sic). Why does it tack an extra `index.html` onto the path given in `alias`?

If I change that directive to

```
location = / {
    index index.html;
    alias /srv/app/static/;
}
```

the error log shows it's trying to access `/srv/app/stati` (sic, it removes the final `c` character from `/srv/app/static`. What's going on here?

## Edit:

I can get the behavior I want using `rewrite` like this:

```
location = / {
    rewrite (.*) /static/index.html;
}
```

But, I think `alias` is more performant and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set `root` already, there is no need for `alias`.

You could achieve the same result with just

```
location = / {
    index index.html;
}
```

As for your funny issues, a look at the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) mentions that `The location part of the request is dropped in the request Nginx issues.`

Basically, this means that with

```
location = / {
    alias /srv/app/static/index.html;
}
```

Accessing `/` actually tries to access `/srv/app/static/index.html` **as a directory**. I assume nginx appends a index.html as part of the global `nginx.conf`.

As for your getting `/srv/app/stati` in the error log, I'm not exactly sure what's going as well. Perhaps you could paste the full log entry?